# Trying to use scp to download file from EC2 returns No such file or directory even though file exists

Tags: amazon-ec2, scp

I am attempting to download a file, `file.tar.gz`, from an EC2 instance. The file exists at this location on the EC2 instance.

```
/home/username/file.tar.gz
```

When I run the command

```
scp -i ~/my_file.pem username@ec2-34-231-112-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/username/file.tar.gz  ~/
```

It returns `/home/username/file.tar.gz: No such file or directory`.

The path is puts in the error message is the correct path to the file as far as I can tell so I am confused what I could be missing that is producing this error.  If anyone can point me in the right direction on how to fix the command it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks ok to me. Are you sure the DNS name resolves to the correct host? Try adding the verbose flag to `scp`. It will give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `/` on your target url, just after the public DNS. Also, if you don't have directory called `home` inside your user's home, you don't need to add it.

```
scp -i ~/my_file.pem username@ec2-34-231-112-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com:username/file.tar.gz  ~/
```

Comment: Who down vote me? My answer actually works. Was even tested.